# vTiger Customer Portal and Server Admin on different Subdomain / Customer Portal Email not being sent

Tags: php, email, crm, vtiger

I have installed vTiger Server on `http://crm.example.com` and the Customer Portal at `http://portal.example.com` now when i try to create contact with Portal User (Access) the user don't receive email about their login credentials.

**Configuration:**

- Outgoing Mail Server - **OK** (I can send email within Mail
  Maneger)
- Check Portal User - **Checked**
- **config.inc.php** variable `$PORTAL_URL = 'http://portal.example.com';`
- **PortalConfig.php** variable `$Server_Path = "http://crm.example.com";` & `$Authenticate_Path = "http://portal.example.com";`
- vTiger Workflows Settings - *execute this Workflow: Only on the first save*

**Steps to resolve this issue:**

- vTiger Community - No one replayed to users.
- Google - All relate to vTiger Community

**Questions:**

- Is it correct to setup vTiger that way (subdomain)?
- Why no email is being send to contact about there login detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make workflow/scheduler work you need to set up your cron configuration. The way I did this was as follows.

**Start Cron**

First, i check if cron is running by going to

> `http://example.com/vtigercron.php`

After browsers says `Access Denied!`, I did the following process

1. Open **vtigercron.php** in CRM folder
2. Look for this line (42) `PHP_SAPI === "cli"`  and change it to your server setting (mine happen to be `apache2handler` so I would type it as `PHP_SAPI === "apache2handler"`.
3. Make sure these files premissions are `chmod 755` **vtigercron.php**, **vtigercron.bat** *(In `/cron` folder)*
4. Then try to access **vtigercron.php** in the browser like this `http://example.com/vtigercron.php` (if you get `access denied!`, then you need to check file permission), if everything worked then you will see cron log.

**Setting up cron time**
Go to `CRM Setting > Other Settings > Scheduler`

Now try to do a task, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Vtiger Customer Portal login details don't use cronjobs and use a custom function called "SendPortalLoginDetails" and send immediately
 If your outgoing server working fine check the following lists.

1. change $HELPDESK_SUPPORT_EMAIL_ID on config.inc.php
2. define a contact and use mail-tester.com temporary email address to check mail server health.